# remove html element in android WebView without Javascript

Tags: java, android, html, android-webview

I would like to remove some elements from the html-code of a webpage, according to their id, before showing the webpage in WebView.
I know how to do this with Javascript but it's important for my app that Javascript is disabled for WebView.

I wrote about html pasers like jsoup but i can't quite get how to use them for my specific problem. Any suggestions?

Edit:
OK, here is what i've got so far:

I load the HTML into a String and remove undesired elements.

```
 String HTMLResult="";
        String urlText = "http://www.google.com";
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
      URL url = new URL(urlText);
      in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));


      String inputLine;
      while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            HTMLResult += '\n'+ inputLine;

      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      if (in != null) {
        try {
          in.close();
              HTMLResult=HTMLResult.replace("ExampleElement", "");
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
        }
```

This part works fine but is very slow.

I tried to load the HTML-Code into WebView with

```
webview.loadData(HTMLResult, "text/html", null);
```

but I only get the code displayed in textform in the Webview window.

Thanks you,
Pascal

Comment: no suggestions without any code example from you. be more specific!

Answer (score 1):

You should get the source html from outside the webview, then parse it as raw data, modify what you want, and give the webview your processed html.

Answer (score -1):

Use Jsoup library to Achieve this.

https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("your url").ignoreContentType(true).get();
Elements ele = doc.select("class to remove").remove();
webView.loadData(doc.toString(),"text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```